# How can I integrate an AVERAGEIFS call into my main script?

Tags: excel, typescript, excel-formula, office-scripts

So far, I am trying to integrate the worksheet function "AVERAGEIFS" into my main code block in Excel Office Scripts. I want to use it in a similar way to how VBA handled it, where I could call the function within my main code. Here, it would push to `avgAvai` the `averageifs` value for the given input. It would take the average of all of the values in the P column whose D column matched a given input.

However, I can't understand how to use await/context to do so. When I attempt to put this into my main function, it  reports a problem that `property: 'Function' does not exist on type: 'Workbook'.`

```
let avgAvai: number[];
for (let rowIndex = 3; rowIndex < rowCount; rowIndex++){
if ((usedRangeValues[rowIndex][15] != 0) && (usedRangeValues[rowIndex+1][15] = 0) ){
avgAvai.push(workbook.function.averageifs("P:P", "D:D", usedRangeValues[rowIndex][3]))
}
}
```

How would I work to integrate this?

Comment: Very much a stab in the dark, but you may have to write the formula to a cell, calculate it, and then read back the result. Has your research suggested that the API supports a function call like the one you propose?

Comment: Office Script doesn't support a method equivalent to `Application.WorksheetFunction` in VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Office Script` does not support a method equivalent to `Application.WorksheetFunction` in VBA.

- Using a UDF to simulate `AverageIf`

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    // for testing
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    let rowCount = 5;
    let usedRangeValues = selectedSheet.getUsedRange().getValues();
    // ***
    let avgAvai: number[] = [];
    for (let rowIndex = 3; rowIndex < rowCount; rowIndex++) {
        if ((usedRangeValues[rowIndex][15] != 0) && (usedRangeValues[rowIndex + 1][15] = 0)) {
            avgAvai.push(getAverageIf(selectedSheet, usedRangeValues[rowIndex][3] as string))
        }
    }
}

function getAverageIf(selectedSheet: ExcelScript.Worksheet, criteria: string): number {
    const avgFormula = "=AVERAGEIF(D:D,\"@\",P:P)"
    const tmpCellLoc = "AA1" // modify as needed
    let tmpCell = selectedSheet.getRange(tmpCellLoc);
    tmpCell.setFormulaLocal(avgFormula.replace("@", criteria));
    let returnVal = tmpCell.getValue() as number;
    tmpCell.setValue("");
    return returnVal;
}
```

- If you don't want to use a temp cell, please try below.

```js
function getAverageIf(selectedSheet: ExcelScript.Worksheet, criteria: string): number {
  let lastRow = selectedSheet.getRange("D:D").getLastCell().getRangeEdge(ExcelScript.KeyboardDirection.up).getRowIndex() + 1;
  let valueD = selectedSheet.getRange("D1:D" + lastRow).getTexts();
  let valueP = selectedSheet.getRange("P1:P" + lastRow).getValues();
  let resP: number[] = [];
  let rowCount = valueD.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
    if (valueD[i][0] === criteria) {
      resP.push(valueP[i][0] as number)
    }
  }
  let sum = resP.reduce((acc, num) => acc + num, 0);
  let average = sum / resP.length;
  return average;
}
```